# Bind Salesforce Service Cloud Snap-Ins for Mobile Apps SDK for Xamarin

Tags: ios, sdk, bind, objective-sharpie

Is it possible to bind the Salesforce Service Cloud Snap-ins SDK provided at this link [iOS SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/SnapinsMobile) to **Xamarin** using Objective Sharpie.

The following is the structure of the SDK. 
[sdk_structure_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihy92.png)